# Extract Abstract from Research Publications (.txt)

Tags: java, netbeans-8, text-extraction

Iam ranking the referenced papers in a Research Paper, I have downloaded them from google scholar, and converted those pdf files into (.txt). Now I want to extract the paragraph with the heading Abstract only.! I have written the code but the problem is it extracts whole document. Kindly have a look on the code, and guide me.!

```
    PDFManager pdfManager = new PDFManager();
           pdfManager.setFilePath("D:\\paper.pdf");
           //System.out.println(pdfManager.ToText());

        PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter("D:\\test.txt");
        outputfile.print(pdfManager.ToText());
        outputfile.close(); 


  try{

      FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("D:\\test.txt");

      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      String strLine;

      while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {

      System.out.println (strLine);
      }

      in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
      }
    }
```

And this is my pdfManager.class

```
package pdftext;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFile;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class PDFManager {

   private PDFParser parser;
   private PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;
   private PDDocument pdDoc ;
   private COSDocument cosDoc ;

   private String Text ;
   private String filePath;
   private File file;

    public PDFManager() {

    }
   public String ToText() throws IOException
   {
       this.pdfStripper = null;
       this.pdDoc = null;
       this.cosDoc = null;

       file = new File("D:\\information.pdf");
       parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(file,"r")); // update for PDFBox V 2.0

       parser.parse();
       cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
       pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
       pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
       pdDoc.getNumberOfPages();
       pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
       pdfStripper.setEndPage(10);

       // reading text from page 1 to 10
       // if you want to get text from full pdf file use this code
       // pdfStripper.setEndPage(pdDoc.getNumberOfPages());

       Text = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
       return Text;
   }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

}
```

Comment: As you already have extracted the text and are working with the text files,  this is no [tag:pdfbox] or [tag:text-extraction] question anymore,  is it?

Comment: see now, iam sorry i didnt include the pdfbox code, to convert the downloaded pdf paper to text, as i already mentioned, i have extracted, but it aint my desired output.! I only want the abstract out of it... ! so that  I could finally apply the cosine similarity algorithm on it..!

Comment: So how do you expect the abstract to be recognized, be it in PDF or text form?

Comment: Well, I can do it from pdf and text both, provided there is guidance. I just want abstract, either from pdf or text.

Comment: If you really want the abstract, surely you have had a look at quite a number of example documents and have determined some criteria by which in those documents the start and end of the abstract can be recognized.So which are they?

Comment: absolutely, I have surfed a lot. One easy solution is to convert the pdf to xml by using www.pdfx.com, and extraction is easy by just selecting the element "Abstract". but it has a threshold, not more than 10 papers could be converted in a day. Therefore, Iam back to pdf n text.! I've seen to extract a page from pdf, some specific lines from txt, but none can fulfill my work, and Iam literally out of options now. My idea is 1) extract the first paragraph frm txt or pdf file, or extract the paragraph with the heading "Abstract" and I have tried for (.txt) but failed.! Iam in utmost need of help

Comment: So if you have determined the criteria, which are they?

Answer (score 0):

```
File fileName = new File("D:\\testa.txt");
    try {
        String startToken = "Abstract";
        String endToken = "1";

        boolean output = false;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileName);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            if (!output && line.indexOf(startToken) > -1) {
                output = true;
                line = line.substring(line.indexOf(startToken)+startToken.length());
            } else if (output && line.indexOf(endToken) > -1) {
                output = false;
                System.out.println(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(endToken)));
            }

            if (output) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I finally managed to do so using scanning, the start token, and the ending token...!